# Access files on a wearable device (camera) with Python in Windows

Tags: python, windows, camera

I wrote a short program in Python that should copy new files from a camera that is connected to a Windows PC, but I just figured out that the camera has no path like a normal USB drive or something.

Instead of just *"F:\Canon EOS 1100D\SD..."* or something similar, the only accessible path to the camera is *"Computer\Canon EOS 1100D\SD..."*.

Python is as expected not able to use those paths. Does an alternate path exists or is it possible to access these files with an plugin?

Comment: You may be able to use [WPD Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd389295) via `win32com.client`. There's a program named [WpdDeviceInspector.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd389273) that will enumerate available devices and their capabilities. I haven't used this before, so that's as much as I can offer you.